# Prevent deadlock between stored procedure and view execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a stored procedure that inserts data into 3 tables (certain parts stored in separate tables, versioning of the orders on updates):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpecialOrders_Insert]
    @lastName nvarchar(100),
    @firstName nvarchar(100),
    @productId int,
    @blabla nvarchar(100),
    @special1 nvarchar(100),
    @special2 nvarchar(100),
    @special3 nvarchar(100),
    @changedBy int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @lastChangedDate datetime = GetDate();
    DECLARE @identity int

    BEGIN TRAN;

        -- Place Order-Head
        INSERT INTO dbo.Orders_H 
                    (LastName
                    , FirstName
                    , ProductId) 
        VALUES 
                    (@lastName,
                    @firstName,
                    @productId);

        SET @identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        -- Place Order-Data (expect lot more data here)
        INSERT INTO dbo.Orders_D
                    (ParentId
                    , Blabla
                    , LastChangedDate
                    , LastChangedBy
                    , ValidFrom
                    , ValidTo)
        VALUES
                    (@identity
                    , @blabla
                    , @lastChangedDate
                    , @changedBy
                    , @lastChangedDate
                    , null);


        INSERT INTO dbo.SpecialOrders_D
                    (ParentId
                    , Special1
                    , Special2
                    , Special3
                    , LastChangedDate
                    , LastChangedBy
                    , ValidFrom
                    , ValidTo)
        VALUES
                    (@identity
                    , @special1
                    , @special2
                    , @special3
                    , @lastChangedDate
                    , @changedBy
                    , @lastChangedDate
                    , null);

    COMMIT TRAN;
END
```

And several views that always read the current versions like:
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SpecialOrders] AS

```
    SELECT 
        -- Orders_H
        h.Id, h.LastName, h.FirstName, h.ProductId,

        -- Orders_D (expect lot more columns here)
        d.Blabla, 

        -- Specialorders (also here more data expected)
        s.Special1, s.Special2, s.Special3

    FROM Orders_H h
         left join Orders_D d ON h.Id = d.ParentId
         left join SpecialOrders_D s ON d.ParentId = s.ParentId

    WHERE d.ValidTo is null and s.ValidTo is null
```

Currently we run into deadlocks when the SP inserts data and the view reads data simultaneously. The sp holds an exclusive lock on Orders_H while the view holds an shared lock on Orders_D.

**How can I modify the view so that it guarantees to read data in the correct order: Orders_H, Orders_D, Specialorders?**

Comment: Can you share an .xdl? I suspect it is an order-of-index-access issue. Any chance you can implement read committed snapshot isolation?

Comment: why not use WITH #NOWAIT

Comment: @AaronBertrand I try to produce an xdl with the reduced scenario above. The real scenarion uses lot more columns and some fk's and so. I am not sure if RCSI is a good idea. Aren't there significant performance issues when dealing with highly updated tables?

Comment: @Hogan no, it's not an option.

Comment: Well, do you like to troubleshoot deadlocks, or tune tempdb? Almost everything is a trade-off.

Comment: If all the SP does is insert data and you're ok with the risk of reading un-committed data, then couldn't you use WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) or WITH (NOLOCK)?

Comment: I want to troubleshoot deadlocks. And if there is an option without RCSI I'ld prefer that one.

Comment: Nope. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46261/dont-use-a-transaction-for-stored-procedure